# How to restore unstaged changes

Tags: git, visual-studio, commit, reset, undo

I am using Visual Studio for git-stuff. And I somehow lost my changes, which I want to restore.

These are the steps I performed:

1) Using VS: Made a commit, with wrong files: "WrongCommit"

I noticed, that the commit was wrong and **I simply wanted to undo it, so that my project was again ahead of the repository and provided changes to commit.**

2) Using VS: Clicked Revert: "RevertCommit"

Now there were two commits listed in VS: "WrongCommit" and "RevertCommit".
And the local project suddenly was resetted to the state **before** "WrongCommit". So I lost all my changes, but I figured they must still be contained in the "WrongCommit".

I then found this answer "[Stackoverflow: Undo a commit and redo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/927386/9684731)":

```
$ git reset HEAD~                                          # (2)
```

The answer states (as far as I understood), that the command "*[..] undoes the commit and leaves the changes you committed unstaged (so they'll appear as "Changes not staged for commit [..]*". However I **do not have any changes to commit now.**

Here is the exact statement history I used ([Image: Git Commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUI4p.png)), where you can see, that git even says 'Unstaged changes after reset', but these changes are just gone.

**How can I still recover those changes?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `git reflog ScreenViewer` to find the commit hash of WrongCommit. Suppose it's `abc123`. Then run:

```
git reset abc123 --hard
git reset HEAD~
git status
#modify files if necessary, and then git add the right files and git commit
```

Comment: Thanks! This put me on the right track, alltough I did `reset HEAD@{7} --soft`. And what's the difference between `HEAD~1` and `HEAD@{1}` anyway?

Comment: @RUL see https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html#gitrevisions-emltrevgtltngtemegemmaster3em and https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html#gitrevisions-emltrefnamegtltngtemegemmaster1em

Comment: Allright. `HEAD~1` means the last commit, wherease `HEAD@` is there to refere directly to the reflog lines.